# How to force navigateByUrl() to navigate the domain root in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular9

My Angular project running on `http://project.test/admin`. I try to navigate the user to start a download from the `http://project.test/api/download/pdf/1` but the `navgateByUrl()` always start the link with `/admin`.

Here is my code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { InjectorInstance } from 'src/app/app.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent {
  token = localStorage.getItem('token') || '';
  private router: Router = InjectorInstance.get<Router>(Router);

  go(element: any) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/api/download/pdf/' + element.id);
  }
}
```

How can I force the `router.navigateByUrl()` to navigate this url: `http://project.test/api/download/pdf/1`?

Or if it isn't possible, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: You know you do not have to navigate to a given url to download a file, right?

Comment: @David right, I don't have to navigate, but the point is: how can I go to this URL? OR how can I download the file?

Comment: if you add `/` before the provided route it will be appended to current route

Comment: I delete the `/` before the route, but it still goes to the `http://project.test/admin/api/download/pdf/1`

Comment: Sorry my mistake, didn't read the question properly. Adding my answer below

Answer (score 0):

that should work

```
go(element: any) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('api/download/pdf/' + element.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the method `navigateByUrl` is provided by angular `Router` class is for routing inside angular app. Your app is running in url *http://project.test/admin*, so an easy way to navigate to the pdf asset is using `window.open('http://project.test/api/download/pdf/1', '_blank');

Answer (score 0):

Try using :navigate method it may work , it gives you access to relative to and other useful router props also

```
go(element: any) {
  this.router.navigate(['../api/download/pdf/',element.id], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
}
```

// this.activatedRoute is ActivatedRoute